# How to extract only the filename from a url string

Tags: php, url, substring, filenames

I have a URL in which the structure of the first part always changes and last part doesn't.

Using this url as input:

```
https://ig-s-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/17438789_1884899458414605_8605163171642081280_a.jpg
```

I would like to capture:

```
/17438789_1884899458414605_8605163171642081280_a.jpg
```

Can I use `preg_match()` for this?

Other captured filenames would look like:

```
/17438789_1884899458414605_8605163171642081280_a.jpg
/17438789_111111111111_862222222222222642081280_a.jpg
/1741111111111789_1555555555605_812222222081280_a.jpg
```

Comment: Regex you are looking for is /\/([0-9_a-z.]+)$/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regex here. You can explode with `/` and get last item of array

```
$str=" https://ig-s-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/17438789_1884899458414605_8605163171642081280_a.jpg";
$array=explode("/",$str);
echo end($array);
```